# Площадь под графиком функции

Tags: python, функции, pandas, numpy, анализ-данных

Как можно посчитать площадь под графиком функций (2 функции в примере), для интервалов, когда функция больше 0 ?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 12, 100)
y = np.sin(x)*np.exp(-x/4)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

```
x = np.arange(0,3*np.pi,0.1)
y = np.sin(x)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вроде так можно проинтегрировать:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

def f1(x):
  y = np.sin(x)*np.exp(-x/4)
  return y if y > 0 else 0

I = quad(f1, 0, 12)
print(f'Площадь: {I[0]}, погрешность: {I[1]}')

def f2(x):
  y = np.sin(x)
  return y if y > 0 else 0

I = quad(f2, 0, 3*np.pi)
print(f'Площадь: {I[0]}, погрешность: {I[1]}')
```

Вывод:

```
Площадь: 1.6551509942979294, погрешность: 1.8946788582496765e-08
Площадь: 3.9999999999999987, погрешность: 1.2687628725416289e-11
```

Comment: Ну это же численное интегрирование, а не аналитическое, оно всегда будет производиться с какой-то погрешностью, зависящей от конкретного метода интегрирования. При желании можно уменьшить погрешность, передав дополнительные параметры.

Comment: Хотя сильно уменьшить погрешность похоже не получится, там уже ограничение методов сказывается